# Print a part of the string

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
"apples = green"
```

How do I print:

1. print everything before '=' (apples)
2. print everything after '=' (green)
3. specify a number of the string in a text file. I have .txt file which contains:

   ```
   apples = green
   lemons = yellow
   ... = ...
   ... = ...
   ```

Comment: What is does 'specify a number of the string in a text file' *mean*? Can you clarify please?

Comment: .txt file (1.apples = green 2.lemons = yellow 3. ...) 1.2.3. - numbers of strings in the .txt file

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more detail. Are those separate lines? Are the numbers part of the file or are they line numbers? You need to be *clear* as to what your input is and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what you expect to be returned; you want to know that `apples = green` is the first line, or do you just want a function to read a specific line (such as the 3rd line, or the 1st line)?

Answer (score 6):

1. split the string using [`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

   ```
   print astring.split(' = ', 1)[0]
   ```
2. still split the string using `.split()`:

   ```
   print astring.split(' = ', 1)[1]
   ```

   Alternatively, you could use the [`.partition()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

   ```
   >>> astring = "apples = green"
   >>> print astring.split(' = ', 1)
   ['apples', 'green']
   >>> print astring.partition(' = ')
   ('apples', ' = ', 'green')
   ```

   Partition always only splits *once*, but returns the character you split on as well.
3. If you need to read a *specific* line in a file, skip lines first by iterating over the file object. The [`itertools.islice()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is the most compact way to return that line; don't worry too much if you don't understand how that all works. If the file doesn't have that many lines, an empty string is returned instead:

   ```
   from itertools import islice

   def read_specific_line(filename, lineno):
       with open(filename) as f:
           return next(islice(f, lineno, lineno + 1), '')
   ```

   To read the 3rd line from a file:

   ```
   line = read_specific_line('/path/to/some/file.txt', 3)
   ```

   If instead you need to know what the line number is of a given piece of text, you'd need to use the [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the line count so far:

   ```
   def what_line(filename, text):
       with open(filename) as f:
           for lineno, line in enumerate(f):
               if line.strip() == text:
                   return lineno
       return -1
   ```

   which would return the line number (starting to count from 0), or -1 if the line was not found in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Every string in python has a function within it called 'split.' If you call string.split("substring") It creates a list which does exactly what you are looking for.

```
>>> string = "apples = green"
>>> string.split("=")
['apples ', ' green']
>>> string = "apples = green = leaves = chloroplasts"
>>> string.split("=")
['apples ', ' green ', ' leaves ', ' chloroplasts']
```

So, if you use string.split(), you can call the index in the resulting list to get the substring you want:

```
>>> string.split(" = ")[0]
'apples'
>>> string.split(" = ")[1]
'green'
>>> string.split(" = ")[2]
'leaves'
```

etc... Just make sure you have a string which actually contains the substring, or this will throw an IndexError for any index greater than 0.